# Runtime error with udf in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, udf

I'm trying to create a new column in a DataFrame.  This new column will contain a formatted data string created from a Long timestamp in milliseconds.

I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/Dataset;
```

It occurs in this code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SQLContext}
import joptsimple.OptionParser
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
    .
    .
    .
    val formatDateUDF = udf((ts: Long) => {
      new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(ts)
    })
```

I'm using the following dependencies in build.sbt:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  // Spark dependencies
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.11" % "2.1.1" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.11" % "2.1.1" % "provided",
  // Third-party libraries
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4",
  "net.sf.jopt-simple" % "jopt-simple" % "5.0.3",
  "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.1",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.1" % "test",
  "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.9.9"
)
```

I'm open to other ways of doing this that might be easier (or, at the very least, work).

Comment: Why not using [unix_timestamp](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@unix_timestamp(s:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,p:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) instead of a UDF?

Comment: the error seems not in udf but where you are reading data from jdbc and converting to dataset. So please update your question with the reading part as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `from_unixtime` method should work better I think?

```scala
val input = List(
  ("a",1497348453L),
  ("b",1497345453L),
  ("c",1497341453L),
  ("d",1497340453L)
).toDF("name", "timestamp")


input.select(
  'name,
  from_unixtime('timestamp, "yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").alias("timestamp_formatted")
).show()
```

Output:

```
+----+-------------------+
|name|timestamp_formatted|
+----+-------------------+
|   a|2017.06.13.12.07.33|
|   b|2017.06.13.11.17.33|
|   c|2017.06.13.10.10.53|
|   d|2017.06.13.09.54.13|
+----+-------------------+
```

Comment: I get at least one error:

[error] /Users/paulreiners/dev/tv-insight-spark-scala/top-20-ocean-ports/src/main/scala/com/transvoyant/insight/ocean/Top20Ports.scala:96: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Symbol
[error]  required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
[error]       from_unixtime('timestamp, "yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").alias("timestamp_formatted")
[error]                     ^
[error] one error found

Comment: Can you share the exact code. Maybe forgot to `import spark.implicits._` or your column is not called `timestamp` ?

Check https://gist.github.com/TomLous/ae2c14633ab1df4349eb7595c988e84b